# Table is empty when search bar is empty or nil

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

When I search for a shop the table gets the right shop. but when I edit my search words ( delete one letter for example ) the table becomes empty. Even when I delete the search words the table becomes empty! I have to go to a different View Controller and come back to the search bar to see the full table.

This is my code

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    shops = shops.filter { $0.shopname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil}


    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Where should I implement `if searchBar.text == "" || searchBar.text ==nill` return the original table cells. or when search again I want it to perform another search.

**UPDATE** 
[image]

my shops array isn't a string type it's a class type that has strings within it. because it's a custom cell with JSON data from api

```
 var shops: [Shops]!
var isSearch = false
var auxiliar : [String] = []
var searchActive: Bool = false



class Shops {
private var _familiy_id: String?
private var _logo : String?

private var _shopname : String?

var familiy_id : String{
    return _familiy_id!
}

   var shopname : String{
    return _shopname!
}
var Logo : String{
    return _logo!
}
init(shopname : String , Logo : String , family_id : String) {

    self._shopname = shopname
           self._logo = Logo
    self._familiy_id = family_id
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
shops = shops.filter {  ... }
```

As you are only applying the filter and overlapping the original array then you will lose the elements. An auxiliary array is needed that helps keep the original.

A simple example: (code updated)

```
import UIKit

class Shops {
    private var _familiy_id: String?
    private var _logo : String?
    private var _shopname : String?

    var familiy_id : String{
        return _familiy_id!
    }

    var shopname : String{
        return _shopname!
    }
    var Logo : String{
        return _logo!
    }
    init(shopname : String , Logo : String , family_id : String) {
        self._shopname = shopname
        self._logo = Logo
        self._familiy_id = family_id
    }
}



class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var shops : [Shops]! = []
    var auxiliar : [Shops]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1 - load data to shops array
        shops.append(Shops(shopname: "Brasil", Logo: "BR", family_id: "1"))
        shops.append(Shops(shopname: "Brasolia", Logo: "BA", family_id: "2"))
        shops.append(Shops(shopname: "Colombia", Logo: "CO", family_id: "3"))
        shops.append(Shops(shopname: "Argentina", Logo: "AR", family_id: "4"))




        // 2  - auxiliar receive the complete original array
        auxiliar = shops

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return auxiliar.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = auxiliar[indexPath.row].shopname
        return cell
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
         auxiliar = shops.filter { $0.shopname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil }
        if searchText == "" {
            // 3 if there is nothing to search, auxiliar receive the complete orihinal array
            auxiliar = shops
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please check my updated question to see the error with my shops array

Comment: No problem, just declare the auxiliar as var auxiliar : [Shops]!   and use the filter form you were using.

Comment: the issue is the `text` in `let temp: NSString = text as NSString`

Comment: thanks :) can't wait to see how this issue is solved

Comment: `shops` has no member range` this is the error actually

Comment: look  " $0.shopname.range  "

Comment: I didn't only write the code, It is run on Xcode and working. Check if you did all changes.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 3** you can use the code like this. You just try this code.

```
import UIKit

class SearchBarTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

  var shops : [String] = ["Brasil", "Argentina", "Colombia", "Chile", "Equador", "Peru", "Uruguai", "Paraguai", "Venezuela"];
  var auxiliar : [String] = []
  var searchActive: Bool = false

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.tableView.dataSource = self
      self.tableView.delegate = self
      self.searchBar.delegate = self
  }

  func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
  {
      self.searchActive = true
  }

  func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
  {
      self.searchActive = false
  }

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
  {
      self.searchActive = false
  }

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
  {
      self.searchActive = false
  }

  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
  {
      self.auxiliar = self.shops.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
      let temp: NSString = text as NSString
      let range = temp.range(of: searchText, options:.caseInsensitive)
     return range.location != NSNotFound
     })

      if self.auxiliar.count == 0
      {
          searchActive = false
      }
      else
      {
          searchActive = true
      }
      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }


  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if searchActive
      {
      return auxiliar.count
      }
      return shops.count
  } 

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
      if searchActive
      {
          cell.textLabel?.text = auxiliar[indexPath.row]
      }
      else
      {
          cell.textLabel?.text = shops[indexPath.row]
      }  
      return cell
  }
```

Comment: appreciate your answer. Can you please look at my updated question to see the error I'm getting because of my `shop` array type